# Problema com Owl Carousel

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

o layout está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, quando utilizo o chamado do script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/owl/owl.theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/owl/owl.carousel.css">
<script src="js/owl/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            pagination : false,
            navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
            singleItem: true,
            autoPlay: true,
            autoHeight: true,
            responsive: true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Simplesmente some! Alguém sabe o que poderia ser?